# Как можно с помощью js сделать анимацию исчезновения и появления блоков с учётом того, что у блоков "tab" display: none;?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
let currentTab = 0 // Текущий таб
showTab(currentTab);

const next = document.querySelector('.next'),
      prev = document.querySelector('.prev');

function showTab(n) { // Отвечает за показ текущего таба и показ кнопки "Назад (prev)"
  let x = document.querySelectorAll('.tab');
  const prev = document.querySelector('.prev');
  x[n].style.display = "block";
  if (n == 0) {
    prev.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    prev.style.display = "inline";
  }
}

next.addEventListener('click', () => { // Логика кнопки "Вперёд (next)" По нажатию на кнопку проверка полей на валидность и смена текущего таба
  let x = document.querySelectorAll('.tab');
  if (!validateForm()) { // Проверка полей на валидность
    return
  }
  if (currentTab <= 2) { // Смена табов
    x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
    currentTab = ++currentTab;
    x[currentTab].style.display = "block";
  }
  showTab(currentTab);
  step(currentTab);
});

prev.addEventListener('click', () => { // Логика кнопки "Назад (prev)"
  let x = document.querySelectorAll('.tab');
  x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
  currentTab = --currentTab;
  x[currentTab].style.display = "block";
  showTab(currentTab);
  step(currentTab);
});

function step(n) { // Показывает на каком ты сейчас вопросе
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
  for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].classList.remove("current-step");
  }
  x[n].classList.add("current-step");
}

function validateForm() {
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    if (y[i].value == "") {
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      valid = false;
    }
  }
  //if (valid) {
  //  document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  //}
  return valid; // return the valid status
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
}

/*================================================================================================================
==================================================================================================================*/

#regForm {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 100px auto;
  font-family: Raleway;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 70%;
  min-width: 300px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;  
}

input {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

/* Mark input boxes that gets an error on validation: */
input.invalid {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
}

/* Hide all steps by default: */
.tab {
  display: none;
}

.tabAnimeOut {
    transition: 1s;
    opacity: 0;
}

.tabAnimeoutIn {
    transition: 1s;
    opacity: 0;
}

button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#prevBtn {
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
}

/* Make circles that indicate the steps of the form: */
.step {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
  border: none;  
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.step.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Mark the steps that are finished and valid: */
.step.finish {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
.current-step{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
<form id="regForm" action="/action_page.php">
  <h1>Register:</h1>
  <!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
  <div class="tab">Name:
    <p><input placeholder="First name..." name="fname"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="Last name..." name="lname"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">Contact Info:
    <p><input placeholder="E-mail..." name="email"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="Phone..." name="phone"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">Birthday:
    <p><input placeholder="dd" name="dd"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="mm" name="nn"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="yyyy" name="yyyy"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">Login Info:
    <p><input placeholder="Username..." name="uname"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="Password..." name="pword" type="password"></p>
  </div>
  <div style="overflow:auto;">
    <div style="float:right;">
      <button type="button" class="prev">Previous</button>
      <button type="button" class="next">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Circles which indicates the steps of the form: -->
  <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
    <span class="step current-step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
  </div>
</form>

<script src="quiz.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Анимацию исчезновения и появления элементов даже с учётом того, что у них меняется свойство с `display: none;` на `display: block;` применить вполне возможно, например путем добавления/удаления дополнительного класса и с помощью правила `@keyframes`, в котором мы можем указать дополнительное свойство, например `opacity`, которое будет анимироваться.

```js
let currentTab = 0 // Текущий таб
showTab(currentTab);

const next = document.querySelector('.next'),
  prev = document.querySelector('.prev');

function showTab(n) { // Отвечает за показ текущего таба и показ кнопки "Назад (prev)"
  let x = document.querySelectorAll('.tab');
  const prev = document.querySelector('.prev');
  x[n].style.display = "block";
  if (n == 0) {
    prev.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    prev.style.display = "inline";
  }
}

next.addEventListener('click', () => { // Логика кнопки "Вперёд (next)" По нажатию на кнопку проверка полей на валидность и смена текущего таба
  let x = document.querySelectorAll('.tab');
  if (!validateForm()) { // Проверка полей на валидность
    return
  }
  if (currentTab <= 2) { // Смена табов
    x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
    x[currentTab].classList.remove('tab__active');
    currentTab = ++currentTab;
    //x[currentTab].style.display = "block";
    x[currentTab].classList.add('tab__active');
  }
  showTab(currentTab);
  step(currentTab);
});

prev.addEventListener('click', () => { // Логика кнопки "Назад (prev)"
  let x = document.querySelectorAll('.tab');
  x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
  currentTab = --currentTab;
  x[currentTab].style.display = "block";
  showTab(currentTab);
  step(currentTab);
});

function step(n) { // Показывает на каком ты сейчас вопросе
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
  for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].classList.remove("current-step");
  }
  x[n].classList.add("current-step");
}

function validateForm() {
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    if (y[i].value == "") {
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      valid = false;
    }
  }
  //if (valid) {
  //  document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  //}
  return valid; // return the valid status
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
}


/*================================================================================================================
==================================================================================================================*/

#regForm {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 100px auto;
  font-family: Raleway;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 70%;
  min-width: 300px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

input {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}


/* Mark input boxes that gets an error on validation: */

input.invalid {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
}


/* Hide all steps by default: */

.tab {
  display: none;
}

.tab__active {
  animation: 3s forwards tab;
}

@keyframes tab {
  0% {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  1% {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.tabAnimeOut {
  transition: 1s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.tabAnimeoutIn {
  transition: 1s;
  opacity: 0;
}

button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#prevBtn {
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
}


/* Make circles that indicate the steps of the form: */

.step {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.step.active {
  opacity: 1;
}


/* Mark the steps that are finished and valid: */

.step.finish {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.current-step {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <form id="regForm" action="/action_page.php">
    <h1>Register:</h1>
    <!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
    <div class="tab">Name:
      <p><input placeholder="First name..." name="fname"></p>
      <p><input placeholder="Last name..." name="lname"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">Contact Info:
      <p><input placeholder="E-mail..." name="email"></p>
      <p><input placeholder="Phone..." name="phone"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">Birthday:
      <p><input placeholder="dd" name="dd"></p>
      <p><input placeholder="mm" name="nn"></p>
      <p><input placeholder="yyyy" name="yyyy"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">Login Info:
      <p><input placeholder="Username..." name="uname"></p>
      <p><input placeholder="Password..." name="pword" type="password"></p>
    </div>
    <div style="overflow:auto;">
      <div style="float:right;">
        <button type="button" class="prev">Previous</button>
        <button type="button" class="next">Next</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Circles which indicates the steps of the form: -->
    <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
      <span class="step current-step"></span>
      <span class="step"></span>
      <span class="step"></span>
      <span class="step"></span>
    </div>
  </form>

  <script src="quiz.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

upd:

```js
let currentTab = 0 // Текущий таб
showTab(currentTab);

const next = document.querySelector('.next'),
  prev = document.querySelector('.prev');

function showTab(n) { // Отвечает за показ текущего таба и показ кнопки "Назад (prev)"
  let x = document.querySelectorAll('.tab');
  const prev = document.querySelector('.prev');
  //x[n].style.display = "block";
  x[n].classList.add('tab__active');
  if (n == 0) {
    prev.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    prev.style.display = "inline";
  }
}

next.addEventListener('click', () => { // Логика кнопки "Вперёд (next)" По нажатию на кнопку проверка полей на валидность и смена текущего таба
  let x = document.querySelectorAll('.tab');
  // if (!validateForm()) { // Проверка полей на валидность
  //   return
  // }
  if (currentTab <= 2) { // Смена табов
    //x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
    x[currentTab].classList.remove('tab__active');
    x[currentTab].classList.add('tab__unactive');
    currentTab = ++currentTab;
    x[currentTab].classList.remove('tab__unactive');
    x[currentTab].classList.add('tab__active');
  }
  showTab(currentTab);
  step(currentTab);
});

prev.addEventListener('click', () => { // Логика кнопки "Назад (prev)"
  let x = document.querySelectorAll('.tab');
  x[currentTab].classList.remove('tab__active');
  x[currentTab].classList.add('tab__unactive');
  //x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
  currentTab = --currentTab;
  x[currentTab].classList.remove('tab__unactive');
  x[currentTab].classList.add('tab__active');
  //x[currentTab].style.display = "block";
  showTab(currentTab);
  step(currentTab);
});

function step(n) { // Показывает на каком ты сейчас вопросе
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
  for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].classList.remove("current-step");
  }
  x[n].classList.add("current-step");
}

function validateForm() {
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    if (y[i].value == "") {
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      valid = false;
    }
  }
  //if (valid) {
  //  document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  //}
  return valid; // return the valid status
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
}


/*================================================================================================================
==================================================================================================================*/

#regForm {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 100px auto;
  font-family: Raleway;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 70%;
  min-width: 300px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

input {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}


/* Mark input boxes that gets an error on validation: */

input.invalid {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
}


/* Hide all steps by default: */

.tab {
  /*display: none;*/
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tab__unactive {
  /*display: none;*/
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: 2s forwards tabOut;
}

@keyframes tabOut {
  0% {
    /*display: block;*/
    max-height: 500px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99% {
    /*display: block;*/
    max-height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    /*display: none;*/
    max-height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.tab__active {
  /*display:block;*/
  animation: 4s forwards tabIn;
}

@keyframes tabIn {
  0% {
    display: none;
    max-height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    display: none;
    max-height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50.1% {
    display: block;
    max-height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    display: block;
    max-height: 500px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#prevBtn {
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
}


/* Make circles that indicate the steps of the form: */

.step {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.step.active {
  opacity: 1;
}


/* Mark the steps that are finished and valid: */

.step.finish {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.current-step {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <form id="regForm" action="/action_page.php">
    <h1>Register:</h1>
    <!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
    <div class="tab">Name:
      <p><input placeholder="First name..." name="fname"></p>
      <p><input placeholder="Last name..." name="lname"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">Contact Info:
      <p><input placeholder="E-mail..." name="email"></p>
      <p><input placeholder="Phone..." name="phone"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">Birthday:
      <p><input placeholder="dd" name="dd"></p>
      <p><input placeholder="mm" name="nn"></p>
      <p><input placeholder="yyyy" name="yyyy"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">Login Info:
      <p><input placeholder="Username..." name="uname"></p>
      <p><input placeholder="Password..." name="pword" type="password"></p>
    </div>
    <div style="overflow:auto;">
      <div style="float:right;">
        <button type="button" class="prev">Previous</button>
        <button type="button" class="next">Next</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Circles which indicates the steps of the form: -->
    <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
      <span class="step current-step"></span>
      <span class="step"></span>
      <span class="step"></span>
      <span class="step"></span>
    </div>
  </form>

  <script src="quiz.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Новый вопрос я удалил, извиняюсь. Но появился ещё один вопрос (если не сложно): При нажатии на кнопку, блок резко скрывается, а нужно плавно. То есть к примеру на скрытие блока две секунды, а на появление одна. Я пытался что-то сделать, но как-то не то... codepen.io/roderen/pen/VwPmwNo

Comment: При нажатии на кнопку вперёд или назад (кнопка назад появляется после первого блока), текущий блок должен плавно скрываться и за ним плавно появляться следующий блок. У меня же вышло только так, что текущий блок скрывается резко (без анимации), а следующий блок появляется как нужно (с анимацией)
https://codepen.io/roderen/pen/jOyVPoE?editors=0110

Comment: Извиняй, что придираюсь.
Как можно решить проблему с "прыганьем" блоков при смене?

Answer (score 0):

Никак.

Анимировать можно только те свойства, для которых существуют исходное, конечное и ПРОМЕЖУТОЧНОЕ состояние.

Например, цвет может быть анимирован (#000000 -> #888888 -> #FFFFFF). Или высота элемента, которая известна и вычислима до того, как будет отрендерен контент (0 -> 34% -> 100%).

А свойство display не может быть анимировано. Сами подумайте каким должно быть промежуточное значение между "block" и "none".